# How to split the list and execute parallelly using java

Tags: java

How to split the list and execute parallelly.
My Scenario--
I am getting 1000+ vehicles using below list from webservices.

```
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = vehicleServices.getVehicles();
```

I want to split 100 vehicles each list and execute all list parallelly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ParallelStream`. Check [the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) to know more abour java parallelism